# "import wx" fails after installation of wxPython on Windows XP

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

I downloaded and installed this version of [wxPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxPython) for use with my Python 2.6 installation:

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.9.1-py26.exe

When I run Python and try to import wx, I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Console2>python
Python 2.6 (r26:66721, Oct  2 2008, 11:35:03) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from wx._core import *
  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_core.py", line 4, in <module>
    import _core_
ImportError: DLL load failed: This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>>>
```

I have already tried removing wxPython and installing again and I got the same error.  How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error.

After some googling found this link to [MSVC++ 2008 Redestributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9B2DA534-3E03-4391-8A4D-074B9F2BC1BF&displaylang=en) and installed it.

That solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Hate to say this, but I had the same problem, and and import worked fine after a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Try the ANSI version instead of the Unicode one. IIRC it needs to match the Python 2.6 install to work properly.

Comment: I tried the ANSI version after removing the unicode version and I still got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

From looking for "application configuration is incorrect" in the [wxPython trac system](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/), the only reference that might make sense is a 64-bit vs 32-bit compatibility issue.

Otherwise, I'd say [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316325/import-wx-fails-after-installation-of-wxpython-on-windows-xp/316466#316466) of trying ANSI is pretty good.

BTW, if you try uninstalling again, make go into the site-packages folder and make sure all the wx and wxPython stuff is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the Microsoft C runtime library v.9 files and manifest. That is, `msvcr90.dll` and `microsoft.vc90.crt.manifest` from folder `python` to the folder wx, tha is, folder which contains failed to start DLLs.

Or install the Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package.

Answer (score 1):

I too have the same issue.Better install "Portable Python" IDE which comes with some nice modules including wxPython .You can start coding GUI immediately without the need to download a separate wxPython.The link ,
http://www.portablepython.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but I had the same problem and solved that by downloading that from their [own website](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php) :  wxPython2.8-win64-unicode-py27
In my case it initially wanted to setup in somewhere else than my python folder. So I changed it to be in ../python27/Lib/SitePackages/
Then it worked properly.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another late answer, but I recently had issues (8/14) and my solution was to use the 32-bit instead of 64-bit wxPython version.

Answer (score 0):

you try to use the module wxpython 2.8.12.1 version, select the version of your python. you can download it here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wxpython